How does the basis for $T_p M$ change from one chart $(U, \phi)$ to another $(\widehat U, \widehat \phi)$?
We can find a basis for $T_pM$ using coordinate charts, and I'd like to understand how to go from one basis to another. I have recorded below what I have in my notes, and I will ask questions in-line.

A vector $v \in T_p M$ can be written as
$$
v = \sum_{i=1}^{n} v^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \quad \text{using } \phi
$$
and
$$
v = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \hat{v}^i \frac{\partial}{\partial y^i} \quad \text{using } \hat{\phi}
$$
How do these representations relate? Note that
$$
\hat{\phi} \circ \phi^{-1} (x^1, \ldots, x^n) = (y^1(x^1, \ldots, x^n), \ldots, y^n(x^1, \ldots, x^n))
$$
where each $y^i: \phi(U \cap \hat{U}) \to \mathbb{R}$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ coordinate function.
To find the coefficients $\{w^i\}$ of a vector
$$
w = \sum_{i=1}^{n} w^i \frac{\partial}{\partial y^i},
$$
we see how $w$ "acts" on the coordinate functions:
$$
w(y^j) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} w^i \frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}(y^j) = w^j.
$$


How do we get $\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}(y^j) = \delta_{ij}$? $\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}$ is a vector in $T_p M$, but I do not yet know how it acts on functions.


So consider
$$
d(\hat{\phi} \circ \phi^{-1})_{\phi(p)} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \right) (y^j)
$$
$$
= \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \left( y^j \circ \hat{\phi} \circ \phi^{-1} \right) \bigg|_{\phi(p)} \tag{1}
$$
$$
= D_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}} \left( y^j(x^1, \ldots, x^n) \right) \bigg|_{\phi(p)} \tag{2}
$$
$$
= \frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^i} (\phi(p)). \tag{3}
$$


How do we go from $(1)$ to $(2)$, and then $(3)$?


Thus,
$$
d(\hat{\phi} \circ \phi^{-1})_{\phi(p)} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \right)
= \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^i} (\phi(p)) \frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}.
$$
This shows how to "change bases" from $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ to $\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}$.
If
$$
v = \sum_{i=1}^{n} v^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \quad \text{(in } \phi \text{ coordinates)}
$$
then
$$
d(\hat{\phi} \circ \phi^{-1})_{\phi(p)} v = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \widehat{v}^j \frac{\partial}{\partial y^j} \quad \text{(in } \hat{\phi} \text{ coordinates)}
$$
where
$$
\widehat{v}^j = \sum_{i=1}^{n} v^i \frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^i}\vert_{\phi(p)}.
$$

Thanks!

Apparently, your ${y^i}_i$ is an orthornomal basis so that $\partial y^j / \partial y^i$ is either $0$ when $i \neq j$ (perpendicular basis elements) and is $1$ when $i = j$ (parallel unit length basis elements)...

@EricTowers Nothing is orthonormal here, there is no inner product

just look up the definition algebraic tangent vector, a derivation.

@psl2Z There's a reason why I asked my question on MSE. I hope someone can help answer it.

well your first question is just applying the definition of the derivation

@stoic-santiago What is the definition of $D$ in Equation (2)? Is it the directional derivative or something else?

@Ikeroy They use $D_v$ to denote the directional derivative in $\Bbb R^n$ along the vector $v$. When they write $D_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}}$, I believe they're using the identification $\Bbb R^n \cong \Bbb R^n_p \cong T_p \Bbb R^n$.

@stoic-santiago I just feel confused with de notation $D_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}}$. I have seen $D_v$ as the classical directional derivative, but $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\in T_p\mathbb{R}^n$ is, in its own, a derivation. I would say the equation $(2)$ is just using redundant notation, but I am not sure.



How do we get $\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}(y^j)=\delta_{ij}$? $\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}$  is a vector in $T_pM$ but I do not yet know how it acts on functions.


The tangent space $T_pM$ (although may be defined in several ways, such us velocities of curves) is the vector space of derivations in $p$, i.e., $\mathbb{R}$-linear maps $v:\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying the Leibnitz rule: $v(fg)=v(f)g(p)+f(p)v(g)$ for all $f,g\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$. One can show that $T_pM$ is in fact a finite dimensional space (with dimension equal to the dimension of the manifold $M$) and a basis can be formed by derivations of the form $\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}:\mathcal{C}^\infty\to\mathbb{R}$, where for all $f\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R})$,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}(f):=\left.\frac{\partial \left(f\circ \widehat{\phi}^{-1}\right)}{\partial y^i}\right|_{\widehat{\phi}(p)},$$
where the right-hand side of the equation is the usual partial derivative in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If we recall the concept of coordinate functions, $y^j\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$ and $y^j(p)$ is the $j$-th coordinate of $\widehat{\phi}(p)$, i.e., $y^j=\pi_j\circ\widehat{\phi}$, where $\pi_j$ denotes the projection onto the $j$-th component. Hence, by taking $f=y^j$ we obtain
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}(y^j)=\left.\frac{\partial \left(\pi_j\circ\widehat{\phi}\circ \widehat{\phi}^{-1}\right)}{\partial y^i}\right|_{\widehat{\phi}(p)}=\left.\frac{\partial \left(\pi_j\right)}{\partial y^i}\right|_{\widehat{\phi}(p)}.$$
If we recall that $\pi_j(y_1,\ldots,y_n)=y_j$, then it is easy to see that $\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}(y^j)=0$ when $j\neq i$ (since we are taking the derivative of a constant) and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}(y^i)=1$ (since we are taking the derivative of a variable with respect of the same one).
Remark: Notice how the writing $\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}$, an element the basis of $T_pM$, is an abuse of notation (although really convenient) of the actual meaning.


How do we go from $(1)$ to $(2)$, and then $(3)$?


Starting from $(1)$ we have the derivation $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ applied to $y^j\circ\widehat{\phi}\circ\phi^{-1}\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. Now, recall that $\phi$ are defined with local coordinates $(x^1,\ldots,x^n)$ and $\widehat{\phi}$ with $(y^1,\ldots,y^n)$. The composition $\widehat{\phi}\circ\phi^{-1}$ is just a change of variables from $\mathbf{x}$ to $\mathbf{y}$, that is, $(y^1(\mathbf{x}),\ldots,y^n(\mathbf{x}))$. Hence, $y^j\circ\widehat{\phi}\circ\phi^{-1}$ is just taking the $j$-the component of this change of variables: $y^j\circ\widehat{\phi}\circ\phi^{-1}(\mathbf{x})=y^j(\mathbf{x})=y^j(x^1,\ldots,x^n)$.
Remark: $D_\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ is a notation that I am not familiary with and notation, specially in differential topology / geometry, tends to be really picky in order to be simplify computations. However, as OP remarked in the comments, I would say it is an identification of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ from $T_pM$ to $T_p\mathbb{R}^n$. Hence, $D_\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ is the derivation corresponding to the partial derivative with respecto to $x^i$.
Now, from $(2)$, as mentioned before, $\left.D_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}}\right|_{\phi(p)}$ denotes the partial derivative with respect the $i$-th component which, moreover, is evaluated in $\phi(p)$. Since $y^j(x^1,\ldots,x^n)$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ we obtain that $\left.D_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}}(y^j(x^1,\ldots,x^n))\right|_{\phi(p)}$ is the classical partial derivative with respect the $i$-th variable evaluated in $\phi(p)$.
